# How to embed Eclipse CDT CSourceViewer inside SWT composite

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-cdt

I have set up a multi-page editor plugin in Eclipse and would like to embed the CSourceViewer from Eclipse CDT into a page that also has a couple other elements, like buttons etc. What is the easiest way to do that? I tried something like the following, but this resulted in null pointer exceptions as soon as I try to type something inside the source viewer.

```
    CTextTools textTools= CUIPlugin.getDefault().getTextTools();
    IPreferenceStore store = CUIPlugin.getDefault().getCombinedPreferenceStore();
    CSourceViewer viewer = new CSourceViewer(composite, null, null, false, SWT.MULTI|SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.H_SCROLL| SWT.FULL_SELECTION, CUIPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
    viewer.configure(new CSourceViewerConfiguration(textTools.getColorManager(), store, null, textTools.getDocumentPartitioning()));
    gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    gd.heightHint = 200;
    gd.widthHint = 300;
    viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gd);
```

It works with a normal source viewer. But the CDT CSourceViewer would be really nice to get syntax highlighting etc.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionViewer.handleVerifyEvent(ProjectionViewer.java:1264)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer$TextVerifyListener.verifyText(TextViewer.java:437)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:273)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1122)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:788)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.modifyContent(StyledText.java:7273)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.sendKeyEvent(StyledText.java:8156)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.doContent(StyledText.java:2502)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKey(StyledText.java:5964)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKeyDown(StyledText.java:5995)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText$7.handleEvent(StyledText.java:5682)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1122)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1164)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1160)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1581)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4795)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:343)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4676)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5050)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3767)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Comment: Please provide the NPE stack trace, it will help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @JonahGraham I added the stacktrace. But before analyzig it in depth I hoped that someone could maybe tell if the way I'm trying to achieving this is right or completely wrong.

Comment: You are on the right track, so analyse away.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the Document for the viewer is not set and therefore is null. Adding the following solves it:

```
    Document document = new Document("class Test { };");
    textTools.setupCDocument(document);
    viewer.setDocument(document);
```